# PHPWord : word doc loses table/cell border formating in Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, office365, phpword, symfony5.4

l have a project in Symfony 5, ubuntu 20.04 and l created a functionality to generate word templates using phpWord.
To format the template, I am using the library methods like
->addRow(), ->addCell(), ->addTable(), ->addTableStyle(), etc.

The template is downloaded in docx format and it looks okay in Ubuntu, but when l open it in Windows, all table/cell borders and formatting is gone.

Does anyone have any idea why?
Am I missing any header or do I need to format the template again for Windows OS?